# Can you change MacBook Bluetooth ID so two os can be seen as different hardware?

Tags: macos, bluetooth

Is there a way to change the OSX Bluetooth ID that is used by external Bluetooth devices during automatic paring?

I run 2 or more OSX installations on separate MacBook partitions.  Devices do not automatically re-connect again if a device is paired with partition 1 and partition 2 boots up and tries to connect.  I need to manually unpair the device in OSX and then re-pair it.  Seems this could be avoided by changing the Bluetooth equivalent of an Ethernet MAC address at the OS or driver level because both partitions assign the same address.

Is changing Bluetooth identity possible on macOS or with a tool?

**Partition 1**

[image]

**Partition 2**

[image]

Comment: I am seeing this as wanting to only change the bluetooth address (sometimes referred as BD_ADDR)- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703686/difference-between-mac-address-and-bluetooth-address. Is that your problem?

Comment: Correct, I'd like each partition to assign have a unique BT address (see new screenshots)

Comment: @AnthumChris - got it, 1) run `ifconfig` and list result if you please, 2) run `networksetup -listallhardwareports` and  list result if you please.

Comment: Are there different OS versions running on the two partitions? Because the only difference I see is the first line, `version`, which is, if you check, is in  About this Mac -> System report-> Hardware-> Bluetooth as `Apple Bluetooth Software Version`. I can just guess that it changes with OS updates.

Comment: the same versions are running on both partitions.

Answer (score 1):

## Automatically pair the same set of Bluetooth Devices, while booting MACOS from 2 independent partitions:

## (Each partition contains the whole MACOS)

### Use identical Bluetooth.plist file on multiple partitions:

I presume that your partitions both contain the entire MACOS, and they do not share any system storage space. I recommend simply to:

1. Setup all the Bluetooth devices after booting with partition 1.
2. Copy the `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist` file to a USB drive.
3. Boot from partition 2.
4. Replace the partition 2 `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist` with the file from the USB drive.

Let me know if this worked out for you.

Comment: Hello. Please note the question wasn’t super clear so I’ve edited it. I think the “or” MAC address meant like a MAC address and to change either the Bluetooth or the ethernet. What do you think of the edit and answer together now?

Comment: Give me few more minutes to add more info, please. I started by adding cautionary notes, since it is easy to break, but hard to repair.

Comment: You have days and days to fix it, I just didn’t want you to miss my edit. Great answer after the edit now that it’s focused on bluetooth and not Ethernet.

Comment: extra hardware is not ideal, and I would like to manually change bluetooth device address as I can with `ifconfig` for network interfaces.

Comment: @AnthumChris - I thought that you are trying to avoid manual pairing every time you boot, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: no prob your solution is valid and could work, but extra hardware would be a workaround we'd like to avoid.

Comment: @AnthumChris - Now I am not sure whether you have noticed the 2nd solution, which is software only, I would edit to bring it to front and delete the hardware solution, since you do not like it.

Comment: Unfortunately, copying a preference file is not a good solution for me and I need more granular control, specifically: changing the hardware address. Thanks though.

Comment: MAC addresses are baked in to your communication hardware's ROM. To really change hardware MAC address, you need to change the ROM at least, usually the whole com card, or component. However, some OSs, like MACOS, allow you to spoof the MAC addresses, via software redirection tables.